# Stop unnecessary component rendering

Tags: javascript, mobx, mobx-react

So I have this class :

```
class Dimension {
  @observable name

  @observable label

  @observable active

  @observable color

  @observable data = []
}
```

Now I have a store:

```
class MyStore {
  @observable dimensions = []

  constructor() {
    /** some stuff to fill dimensions **/
  }
}

const MyStoreContext = createContext(new MyStore());

export default MyStoreContext;
```

After an API call to the server I get some data and create Dimension objects and put them in the array.

Now I have two components where I use these dimensions, one where I need the data and one where I don't.

Problem is I have a button that recalculates the data - without changing anything except that, but because I call dimensions as so :

```
const component = observer(() => {
  const store = useContext(MyStoreContext);

  const dimensions = store.dimensions;

  return (
    dimensions.map(dimension => <span style={{color: dimension.color}}> dimension.name </span>)
  )
}

const component2 = observer(() => {
  const store = useContext(MyStoreContext);

  const dimensions = store.dimensions;

  return (
    /** Something with dimension.data **/
  )
}
```

In both places, when there is a change of the data in dimensions (even though I don't use it) the component still re renders.

I wonder how can I use dimensions in both places but to make sure only what is necessary gets rendered.

Must I pass the dimensions as props to the component?

Answer (score 0):

I've tried to reproduce your behaviour but could not do it. Everything works as expected, if you change only `data` part of dimension then only components which use this `data` field will be rerendered.

https://codesandbox.io/s/httpsstackoverflowcomquestions63157530-p6fcs?file=/src/App.js

Try to compare your code with mine, maybe there is some differences?